# Compare many files at once with Vista?

Tags: debugging, file, comparison

I have a project composed of 100s of files. One version contains a bug that the other does not. Is there some tool I can use to compare everything at once? I was thinking I could examine each difference to see if it's causing the problem. (There wouldn't be too many differences, it's just a matter of finding them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Windows, [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) is awesome++, it can diff entire trees of folders and show you exactly the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of `diff` utility. On Linux or Cygwin, a simple `diff -r /path1 /path2` will give you all of the differences between two trees. You may also be able to find graphical diff programs for your platform of choice.

Answer (score 0):

[diff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) can easily compare two trees, and present you all changes in a sequential manner.

Answer (score 0):

BeyondCompare is great!